# Preencher inputs dinamicamente após mudança em select

Tags: php, javascript, select, input

Boa tarde, preciso de ajuda com uma parte do código. Basicamente tenho um formulário com dois selects(**aluno_id, produto_id**) e alguns inputs(**produto_preco,quantidade,preco_total**), utilizo funções para preencher arrays e então os selects pelo ID e mostrar pelo nome.

Agora preciso fazer com que cada vez que o select dos produtos for alterado, faça um busca pelo ID no array dos produtos, e preencha o input **produto_preco** com o preço equivalente ao **produto_id**. Pelo que pesquisei isso é feito com Javascript e JSON, e possivelmente Ajax, fiz algumas tentativas porém não obtive sucesso.

Lembrando que os dados desse form serão cadastrados no BD depois.

```
<?php require_once("cabecalho.php");
require_once("banco-vendas.php");
require_once("banco-aluno.php");
require_once("banco-produto.php");

$venda = array("aluno_id" => "1", "produto_id" => "1",
"quantidade_produto" => "", "preco_produto" => "", "valor_total" => "",
"data_operacao" => "");
$listaPreco = listaPreco($conexao); // cria um array tridimensional 
listaPreco com id, nome, preco
$alunos = listaAlunos($conexao);    // cria array alunos
$produtos = listaProdutos($conexao);  // cria array produtos

$teste = array_search('2', array_column($listaPreco,'id')); // teste filtro 


?>

<h1>Formulário Vendas</h1>
<form action="adiciona-venda.php" method="post">
  <table class="table">
    <?php include("vendas-formulario-base.php"); // inputs e selects do 
formulario?>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('select[name="produto_id"]').on('change', function(){ // select produtos
  var teste = "<?php Print($teste);?>";
  // var ar = <?php json_encode($listaPreco) ?>;
  // alert(ar);
  $("#cont").val(teste); // input preco


});
</script>
<?php include("rodape.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo as dicas do @João-Jácome, fiz apenas algumas modificações: 
Adicionei um FOR para percorrer o Array, e um If para encontrar o produto_id correspondente ao ID. 
O código Javascript ficou assim:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('select[name="produto_id"]').on('change', function(){ // select produtos

   var listaPrecosProdutos = <?php echo json_encode($listaPreco);?>;
   var produto_id = $(this).val();

   for (i = 0; i<listaPrecosProdutos.length;i++){
     if (produto_id == listaPrecosProdutos[i].id){
       $("#cont").val(listaPrecosProdutos[i].preco);
     } else{

     }
   }

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que a variavel `$listaPreco` siga a seguinte estrutura:

```js
{ produto_id: valor, produto_id2: valor }
```

Você pode armazenar esse valor em uma variavel do JavaScript (como você já estava fazendo), e acessar o índice referente ao produto selecionado.

```js
$('select[name="produto_id"]').on('change', function(){ // select produtos
    var listaPrecosProdutos = <?php echo json_encode($listaPreco);?>;
    var produto_id = $(this).val();
    $("#cont").val(listaPrecosProdutos[produto_id]);
});
```

Comment: Se eu der um Print no array listaPreco, ele sai no seguinte formato:`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [nome] => Produto1[preco] => 10 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [nome] =>produto2 [preco] => 20 ) )` Testei seu código e aparentemente ele retorna o ID do produto selecionado, porém não mostra nada no input. Pois retorna undefined quando utilizado o `listaPrecosProdutos[produto_id]`